# Class method and constructor confusion in java

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I have a class that has the duty of creating a simple method with two input parameters. The method needs to be used in the creation of other methods in other classes. My question is, does the way I wrote it seem correct? and when calling this method in another class, what would it look like?

```
public class IntlDensity {

    static double p = PhysicalConst.pi; 

    public IntlDensity(double m, double r) {
    }

    public double irho (double mass, double rad) {
       return(mass/(((4.0/3)*p*Math.pow(rad, 3))));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have already.  How are you with [design patterns](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/) in Java?

Comment: I dont remember why I made a constructor and then a method below it. Is this so I can use the constructor to call the method from another class?

Comment: If `pi` is suppose to be constant then name it `PI` (it is convention). Also if it is constant then why do you create separate static field for it? Cant you just use `PhysicalConst.PI` in your calculations? If you want to have its shorter version use `static import` it and use just `PI`.

Comment: Yes I believe I could. I dont believe it would look as clean in the calculation as I want, though. I will chance to PI to follow the convention. Also the import utility will b used, thanks. I am mostly having trouble with the method itself.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
public class PhysicalBody {

    private double mass;
    private double rad;

    public PhysicalBody(double m, double r) {
        this.mass = m;
        this.rad = r;
    }

    public double getIrho() {
       return(mass/(((4.0/3)*PhysicalConst.pi*Math.pow(rad, 3))));
    }

    public double getMass() { return mass; }
    public double getRad() { return rad; }
}
```

This creates a new object storing the `mass` and `rad` you specified in the constructor, you can then query the irho of that object on demand. Note that I've named the class to better describe what it contains. Think in terms of objects, not in terms of activities.

You can now add further methods as you desire.

In general pulling static values in from another class and duplicating them the way you were doing is a bad idea - just either reference it like I have here or do a static import so you don't need the `PhysicalConst.` all the time but are still actually referencing the same value.

You could also consider making the mass and rad constant depending on whether you anticipate them ever changing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your constructor is useless because you don't do anything with the passed in parameters.
2. Don't create a new static fields that references an existing other static field
3. Pi is defined as a constant in Math so don't define it in the other package either
4. Irho should be static since it doesn't use any members of the class.

Depending on your actual code you may want to pass mass, etc. to the constructor and don't pass anything to irho, although math classes often are fine with only static fields and methods.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, whether you are new or a seasoned veteran, you will always look back at code and realize it could've been better.

In this case, there is no magical way to know if you could write your class "better," but you hint at the best way--the view of a client of your class. In other words, imagine how the code that uses `IntlDensity` will look.

One way to do that is to use [Test-Driven Development](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html). That takes some getting used to, but unit testing as a general matter is a great way to refine the API of your class so it makes sense to its callers.

One point I can make though about this class is that you should probably use your constructor:

```
public class IntlDensity {
    private double mass;
    private double rad;

    public IntlDensity(double mass, double rad) {
      this.mass = mass;
      this.rad = rad;
    }

    public double irho() {
       return mass/(((4.0/3) * PhysicalConst.PI * Math.pow(rad, 3)));
    }
}
```

Then your client will do this:

```
IntlDensity id = new IntlDensity(5, 10);
System.out.println(id.irho());
```

Of course this depends on what you are trying to do. That's why thinking in terms of your callers matters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making your method `static` like so -

```
public class IntlDensity {
  private static final double PI = PhysicalConst.pi;     // A local PI constant?

  public static double irho(double mass, double rad) {   // Static
    return (mass / (((4.0 / 3) * PI * Math
        .pow(rad, 3))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to instantiate a `IntlDensity` object?  If not, you could just make the method static and invoke it

```
...
IntlDensity.irho(5,2);

public class IntlDensity {

    static double p = PhysicalConst.pi; 

    public static double irho (double mass, double rad) {
       return(mass/(((4.0/3)*p*Math.pow(rad, 3))));
    }
}
```